# Bootstrap4 сделать выпадающее меню на всю ширину экрана

Tags: css, bootstrap, dropdown

Необходимо выпадающее меню `dropdown` растянуть на всю ширину экрана.

Сделала [так](https://jsfiddle.net/3y46Lq5k/2/):

```
.nav > li.dropdown.show {
 position: static;
}

.nav > li.dropdown.show .dropdown-menu { 

  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
   right: 0;
 }

.dropdown-menu > li {
 display: table-cell;
 height: 5rem;
line-height: 5rem;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .dropdown-menu > li {
display: block;
}
}
```

К сожалению в fiddle не отобразилось, но выпадающее меню растянулось на ширину `container`, а не на ширину экрана.

Как растянуть `dropdown` на всю ширину экрана?

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то `.nav > li.dropdown.show .dropdown-menu` замените следующим:

```
li.dropdown.show > .dropdown-menu { 
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: auto ;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Протестить ваш вариант можно [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/1fsvcusp/)

Comment: выглядит почти как требуется, но `position: fixed !important;` не подходит. почему `width: 100%;` не работает?

Comment: `width: 100%` работает, заменил.

Comment: но почему без `position: fixed;` не работает... я применила это http://codepen.io/danielmdesigns/pen/QbgYKa, но не сработало как надо